# Hosting WCF Service in IIS7

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, iis, iis-7

All,

I have scoured this group, etc. to no avail. I have successfully hosted a WCF (Web) service in IIS7. The problem is that when IIS exposes the endpoint to the service, it used the server's local/DNS name, e.g., MyServer. I need to expose the service to machines outside my network, and this name (MyServer) is not exposed externally. I want to somehow force IIS to use a name I give it vs. using the local/DNS name of the machine on which the service is hosted.

I have tried configuring IIS to use host names/binding, but when I do that, all I ever get from IIS is "bad hostname" - it can't resolve the address to the service/.svc file. I have tried IP + host name, IP alone, hostname alone, various web.config file setting (some of the settings are difficult to follow, I might add)... all yield some sort of error.

This must be a pretty "bread and butter" thing to do... It there a straightforward solution?

Thanks,
John

Comment: If you want to expose it outside your network, wouldn't an interstitial device outside the realm of wcf route a request for the external IP/Name to your internal server. I don't think this is in WCF's realm. External Request -> Your Company's firewall/device -> translated and routed to -> MyServer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a wildcard in the BaseAddress configuration:

```
<host>
    <baseAddresses><add baseAddress="http://*/MyService" /></baseAddresses>
</host>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem. I need to expose the service under a name that is different from the local machine name (I want to expose it under the machine's external IP). I can't believe this is so complicated.